# Why is my div floating to the right?

Tags: html, css

I have simple HTML document with 3 div's. The first 2 divs needs to float to left and the 3 div needs to float to the right. I am keeping the styles inline just for demonstration purposes.

I am trying to get the second div element to float to the left but it keeps floating to the right. This is the div element I am trying to have to float to the left

```
<div style="width: 200px; float: left">Left Div #2</div>
```

Can anyone please help me correct this? Thank you!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


<div style="width: 70%; float: left; clear: left">Left Div</div>
<div style="width: 200px; float: left">Left Div #2</div>


<div style="width: 30%; float: right; clear: right">Test</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The maximum `width` is 100% so you have 3 `divs`, 2 of them in percentage (70+30) which is equal to 100%, plus the 3rd `div`(Left Div #2) that you want to be floated left which has 200px.

So 100%-70-30=0 and 0-200px = -200px.

You have to fix either the `width:70%` or `width 30%` in order to match 100% (with 200px)

For example change your `width:70%` to `width:50%` and it works.

You always can try display them in `inline-block`

**Updated answer based on the OP comment**

you can't have 3 divs with the total more than 100% and what them to appear inline, as you did in your comment: 70%+70%+30% = 140% > 100%.

**this code is working:**

```css
div { 
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
 padding:10px;   
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:top;
 width:30%   
}
.r1 {float:right} /*just because you said you want your 3rddiv floated right */
```

```html
<div class="l1">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sed nunc eu sem bibendum maximus. Quisque ante mi, porta at egestas sit amet, tempor vel ante. Aenean libero risus, mollis id efficitur sed, fermentum in lacus. Quisque ultricies eleifend leo, at convallis dui auctor eu. Vestibulum eu odio varius, sagittis lectus sit amet, varius elit. Aenean tincidunt vel eros in rhoncus. Curabitur sed est lorem. Nam sed lorem vestibulum, sagittis ex nec, euismod ipsum. Donec at eros mollis, pulvinar ex at, porttitor arcu. Integer posuere lectus sit amet nisl volutpat, pharetra commodo risus congue. Aenean tincidunt elit nec pulvinar vestibulum. Suspendisse potenti. Suspendisse volutpat magna nec nisl lacinia accumsan. Donec a auctor ante.
</div>
<div class="l2">Aliquam iaculis id sapien at hendrerit. Phasellus tempus euismod felis et interdum. Mauris vehicula felis sed nisl auctor lacinia. Mauris posuere orci at porttitor viverra. Mauris eget bibendum purus. Cras tristique dignissim ex. Phasellus eu ipsum finibus neque lacinia laoreet et non neque.</div>
<div class="r1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sed nunc eu sem bibendum maximus. Quisque ante mi, porta at egestas sit amet, tempor vel ante. Aenean libero risus, mollis id efficitur sed, fermentum in lacus. Quisque ultricies eleifend leo, at convallis dui auctor eu. Vestibulum eu odio varius, sagittis lectus sit amet, varius elit. Aenean tincidunt vel eros in rhoncus. Curabitur sed est lorem. Nam sed lorem vestibulum, sagittis ex nec, euismod ipsum. Donec at eros mollis, pulvinar ex at, porttitor arcu. Integer posuere lectus sit amet nisl volutpat, pharetra commodo risus congue. Aenean tincidunt elit nec pulvinar vestibulum. Suspendisse potenti. Suspendisse volutpat magna nec nisl lacinia accumsan. Donec a auctor ante.</div>
```

The `box-sizing` properties were added only to add the `padding` property without changing the width of the `divs`, so it is for demonstrations purposes only.

See more info [**here**](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) about box-sizing

See more info [**here**](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/) about display and inline-block

Comment: Dippas. Thanks for the response.  I did that and it solved the problem. But now my right div keeps getting pushed down when add left div elements ... How can I fix that issue. Here is a quick example...

`<div style="width: 70%; float: left; clear: left">Left Div</div> <div style="width: 70%; float: left">Left Div #2</div> <div style="width: 30%; float: right; clear: right">Test</div>`

Comment: you keep doing a mistake: 100% is a total of the screen so 100%-70%-70%-30% = -70%. I will make a fiddle for you and update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `width:70%` to match value.(In my case, `width:30%`)

[This is a jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/awpj732q/)

The reason why is `width:70%` has too much width to push other divs.

Comment: I see what you mean! I have done that but now my right div is being pushed down as well. How to I made it stay on top?

`<div style="width: 70%; float: left; clear: left">Left Div</div>
<div style="width: 70%; float: left">Left Div #2</div>
<div style="width: 30%; float: right; clear: right">Test</div>`

Comment: @elrado88 Impossible. A div maximum width is 100%, **70% + 70% > 100%**.  Unless use `position:absolute`